# Как вывести заголовок выводимого списка подкатегорий?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
С помощью нижеприведенного кода я вывожу списки подкатегорий по заданной в id_cat категории.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id_cat'])){
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT TER.`term_id`, TER.`name` FROM `wp_terms` TER LEFT JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` TAX ON TER.`term_id` = TAX.`term_id` WHERE TAX.`parent`='".abs(intval($_GET['id_cat']))."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            echo "<li><a href='firmlist.php?id_subcat={$row['term_id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></li>";
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Error!';
        }
    }else{
    echo 'Error!';
    }
?>
```

Подскажите плз, как сделать так, чтобы, помимо списка подкатегорий, можно было вывести в заголовок название категории, к которой принадлежит выводимый список подкатегорий? При этом id категории содержится в id_cat, нужно извлечь из таблицы wp_terms параметр name по данному id.

Answer (score 1):

Писать не буду, объясняю алгоритм. Вы **сначала** вытаскиваете название категории, а потом уже список подкатегорий. Можно в 2 запроса для удобства..

P.S. Писал сайт, там на определенной странице шло 100 запросов к базе... И ничего, все быстро работает

Comment: Вот так?

    $head = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id`='".abs(intval($_GET['id_cat']))."'")
    echo $head

Comment: нет, не так. почему так сложно прочитать про то как написать запрос к БД, получить данные из БД, и как их вывести из БД средствами PHP статей на это в нете
[2 ссылки первые][1]


  [1]: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%91%D0%94+php&lr=2


>$res = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM wp_terms WHERE >term_id='".abs(intval($_GET['id_cat']))."'") 
>$head=mysql_fetch_array($res);
>echo $head;

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо, обещаю сам читать))

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id_cat'])){
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `term_id`='".abs(intval($_GET['id_cat']))."'") $head=mysql_fetch_array($res); echo $head;
 }else{
    echo 'Error!';
 }
Не выводит(

Comment: @Shrek че за бред? Какой echo, как минимум 

print_r($head); 

вот так он выведет массив